# Convergence of unitary products on a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

First: I'm sorry for the basic question--I can move it to Math SE if necessary...

Let $X$ be a Hilbert space and suppose $\{U_k\}_k$ is a sequence of unitary operators on $X$. Let $\|\cdot\|$ be the operator norm on $X$. Let $S_n = \{U_k\}_k^n$ and $p(S_n) = U_nU_{n-1}\cdots U_2U_1$.

**Conjecture:** $\{p(S_n)\}_n$ converges uniformly if $\{U_n\}_n\rightarrow I$ ($I$ is the identity), also uniformly.

**My current progress:** If necessary, the assumption can be relaxed to $\{p(S_{nm})\}_m\rightarrow I$ for all $n > m$ as $m\rightarrow\infty$ with $S_{nm} := \{U_k\}_{k=m}^n$. Clearly $p(S_{nm}) = p(S_n)(p(S_m))^*$ so $\|p(S_n)-p(S_m)\|$ converges. Hence $p(S_n)$ is Cauchy and thus converges uniformly since $X$ is a Hilbert space, thus complete. I'm not 100% my reasoning about this however--viz. does the completeness of $X$ imply convergence for sequences of operators as well as points in $X$? Furthermore, I can't think of a good place to start on the conjecture as stated.

Advice is appreciated!

**Update:**

Prof. Israel and Sebastian Goette have provided the counterexample of $U_n =  e^{\alpha i/n}$ ($\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$) for the conjecture. Thus the premise should be relaxed. Thank you all for the help!

Comment: $p(S_n)$ is not a point of $X$, so when you say "it converges in $X$" we appear to have a type error. Could you try to be more precise? For instance, you talk about the induced norm on X, but then you apply this norm to things which are *operators on $X$*. If these things are not clear to you then I agree you might do better to sort some of these things out on MSE first

Comment: Also, you seem to define $S_{nm}$ to be a tuple of operators, but later on you treat it as if it is a single operator...

Comment: Regarding the first question, I have updated it to say converges uniformly in $X$, viz. in the uniform operator topology-- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_topologies. As far as I can see it is perfectly reasonable to say $p(S_n)$ converges this way, so long as the operator topology is specified. I use the same definition of induced norm as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Induced_norm, but will update it to read operator norm. I don't understand the second question. $S_{nm}$ is a two-indexed sequence of operators. $p(S_{nm})$ is a single operator defined by the two indexes.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I think I was confused by terminology that was slightly different to what I'm familiar with

Comment: Your conjecture somehow reminds me of the following statement (that is wrong unless you are in $p$-adic topology): a series converges if the sequence of summands converges to $0$. If fact let $\mathbb C$ be the Hilbert space and $U_n=e^{\pi i/n}$. Wouldn't this give a counterexample? Or is $p(S_n)$ not what I think it is?

Comment: I believe it does indeed, Sebastian. I think Prof. Israel was also getting at this and I was too thick to connect it. To be clear, my interpretation of your point is since $\mathbb{C}$ is commutative, $p(S_\infty) = \exp\{i\pi\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n}\}$, which cannot converge because the exponent includes the harmonic series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the unitary operators $U_n = \exp(i/n) I$.  These converge to $I$, but e.g.
$U_{2m} \ldots U_m \approx \exp(i \ln(2)) I$ does not converge to $I$ as $m \to \infty$.

Comment: Thank you for the response, Prof. Israel! This example makes it clear I can't argue first that $p(S_{nm})\rightarrow I$ then try and argue that $U_n\rightarrow I$ implies $p(S_{nm})\rightarrow I$. Do you have any advice on the conjecture as stated (seems as if this example might be used to defeat it) or whether or not the proof using the relaxed assumption is correct logic?